# Enable Azure SQL Server Auditing with Pulumi

Tags: azure, azure-sql-server, pulumi

I am trying to enable auditing on an Azure SQL server resource with a Pulumi stack. However, the setting never turns on with the script that I have. I've looked at various blogs and ARM templates for how it looks, but the blogs always mention you need to enable auditing on the master database in order to have this setting enabled. The setting I am trying to enable through Pulumi is shown below

[image: Setting to be enabled]

My pulumi stack is shown here:

```
var dbServer = new AzureNative.Sql.Server("dbServer", new AzureNative.Sql.ServerArgs
    {
        ServerName = dbServerName.ToLower(),
        ResourceGroupName = resourceGroupName,
        AdministratorLogin = username,
        AdministratorLoginPassword = password,
        Version = "12.0",
        MinimalTlsVersion = "1.2",
        PublicNetworkAccess = AzureNative.Sql.ServerPublicNetworkAccess.Enabled,
        Tags = tags,
    });

    var serverDiagnosticSetting = new Pulumi.AzureNative.Insights.DiagnosticSetting("serverDiagnosticSetting", new Pulumi.AzureNative.Insights.DiagnosticSettingArgs
    {
        Logs = 
        {
            new Pulumi.AzureNative.Insights.Inputs.LogSettingsArgs { 
                Category = "SQLSecurityAuditEvents", Enabled = true, RetentionPolicy = new Pulumi.AzureNative.Insights.Inputs.RetentionPolicyArgs { Days = 0, Enabled = false, },
            }
        },
        Name = "mydiagnosticsettings",
        ResourceUri = dbServer.Id,
        WorkspaceId = logAnalyticsId,
    }, new CustomResourceOptions(){DependsOn = new InputList<Pulumi.Resource>(){dbServer}});

    var serverBlobAuditingPolicy = new AzureNative.Sql.ServerBlobAuditingPolicy("serverBlobAuditingPolicy", new AzureNative.Sql.ServerBlobAuditingPolicyArgs
    {
        AuditActionsAndGroups = 
        {
            "SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP",
            "FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP",
            "BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP",
        },
        BlobAuditingPolicyName = "sqlAuditingPolicy",
        ResourceGroupName = resourceGroupName,
        ServerName = dbServer.Name,
        State = Pulumi.AzureNative.Sql.BlobAuditingPolicyState.Enabled,
        IsAzureMonitorTargetEnabled = true,
        StorageAccountSubscriptionId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }, new CustomResourceOptions(){DependsOn = new InputList<Pulumi.Resource>(){dbServer}});
```

Running this stack, however, the setting is never enabled.

Comment: I think `BlobAuditingPolicyName` should be named `"Default"` specifically. At least, that's what all ARM templates do.

Comment: Also, the Azure portal seems to create a bunch of those, including `DatabaseBlobAuditingPolicy` (for the `master` database), `ExtendedServerBlobAuditingPolicy`, and `ExtendedDatabaseBlobAuditingPolicy`. I'm not exactly sure which ones you need.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure a diagnostic setting on the server directly.
You have to use the master database URI

```
var databaseMaster = dbServer.Id.Apply(id => id+"/databases/master");

var serverDiagnosticSetting = new Pulumi.AzureNative.Insights.DiagnosticSetting("serverDiagnosticSetting", new Pulumi.AzureNative.Insights.DiagnosticSettingArgs
    {
        Logs = 
        {
            new Pulumi.AzureNative.Insights.Inputs.LogSettingsArgs { 
                Category = "SQLSecurityAuditEvents", Enabled = true, RetentionPolicy = new Pulumi.AzureNative.Insights.Inputs.RetentionPolicyArgs { Days = 0, Enabled = false, },
            }
        },
        Name = "mydiagnosticsettings",
        ResourceUri = databaseMaster,
        WorkspaceId = logAnalyticsId,
    }, new CustomResourceOptions(){DependsOn = new InputList<Pulumi.Resource>(){dbServer}});
```